# MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"

Tags: python, ruby, node.js, msbuild, node-gyp

I am trying to install `nodejs` from a long time now. I tried it searching over the google but seriously i had not got any working solutions.

My first question is that

1. Why Nodejs require Microsoft Visual component?

Secondly as per suggestion on google i tried below things

- Installed Visual C++ 2010 (updated path in the variable) but after
  installing i got many more errors including "MSBUILD : error MSB3428:
  Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
- Went through `https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp` for getting errors   removed but still it is not working.
- Uninstalled and installed Node js again but with no success.

I have following versions as

- Node js 0.12
- Python 2.7
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Windows 7 64 bit.

When i run `npm-install` then the error appears as below

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component 
"VCBuild.exe".To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) 
install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the 
component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.
```

My `package.json` is as below:

```
{
 "name": "TRest",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "devDependencies": {
     "grunt": "~0.4.2",
     "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
     "grunt-sass": "~0.11.0",
     "grunt-pixrem": "^0.1.2",
     "grunt-legacssy": "^0.2.0",
     "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
     "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.3.2",
     "node-bourbon": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you starting npm from a 'Visual Studio commandline' (see start menu)? VCBuild is part of VS2008 (and older) so it looks like npm cannot figure out you have VS2010. Also I don't know what you mean with `(updated path in the variable)` but you shouldn't do anything manually, always run VS command prompt.

Comment: nop.. i am doing npm stuff from `cmd.exe` . updated path means i updated environment variables with visual path

Comment: Well did you set *all* environment variables for VS (there's like 10 of them)? Did you already try using a proper VS command prompt?

Comment: m nt sure of 10 variables.. VS command prompt i cant find

Comment: How is `ruby` a relevant tag for this question?

Comment: because i need ruby also to get somethings to work...

Comment: Start->All Programs->Microsoft Visual Studio 2010->Visual Studio Tools->Developper command prompt

Comment: I have the same problem. But the thing is my company pc is behind a proxy, that's why it complains and  cannot go behind proxy. I don't know how to resolve it :|

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can tell npm to use Visual studio 2010 by doing this...

```
npm install socket.io --msvs_version=2010
```

Replace socket.io with the package that is giving the issue.

It is also possible to set the global settings for npm:

```
npm config set msvs_version 2010 --global
```

Comment: this did it for me, the global command also fixed problems with other packaged like bcrypt.

Answer (score 10):

alternatively try `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

Comment: And a command "npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global" follows it :)

Comment: This works for me. Just add a minor thing: I need to run this in PowerShell (Run as Administrator)

Answer (score 7):

Use the PowerShell with administrative rights and run:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0
```

after that it will work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install strongloop and got this error "MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component “VCBuild.exe”.
I was able to resolve by running this.

find node on your windows with 
$ npm install -g which 
$ which node 
after cd into the directory, inside the directory cd into node_modules\npm folder and finally: 
$ npm install node-gyp@latest

Answer (score 0):

I personally got this because python2 path couldn't be fetched. You can either install python 2 and set the the path in environment variables or find a node-gyp module installed somewhere in your colleagues machine and just paste it in your node_modules folder.